# How to get pandas dataframe where columns are the subsequent n-elements from another column dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, scikit-learn

A very simple example just for understanding.

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':pd.Series([1, 2, 13, 14, 25, 26, 37, 38])})
df 
        A
    0   1
    1   2
    2  13
    3  14
    4  25
    5  26
    6  37
    8  38
```

Set `n = 3`

#### First example

How to get a new dataframe `df1` (in an efficient way), like the following:

```
   D1  D2  D3     T
0   1   2  13    14
1   2  13  14    25
2  13  14  25    26
3  14  25  26    37
4  25  26  37    38
```

Hint: think at the first n-columns as the *data* (Dx) and the last columns as the *target* (T). In the 1st example the target (e.g 25) depends on the preceding n-elements (2, 13, 14).

#### Second example

What if the *target* is some element ahead (e.g.+3)?

```
   D1  D2  D3     T
0   1   2  13    26
1   2  13  14    37
2  13  14  25    38
```

Thank you for your help,
Gilberto

P.S. If you think that the title can be improved, please suggest me how to modify it.

### Update

Thanks to @Divakar and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923617/efficient-numpy-2d-array-construction-from-1d-array) the rolling function can be defined as:

```
import numpy as np
def rolling(a, window):
    shape = (a.size - window + 1, window)
    strides = (a.itemsize, a.itemsize)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)

a = np.arange(1000000000)
b = rolling(a, 4)
```

In less than 1 second!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see how we can solve it with NumPy tools. So, let's imagine you have the column data as a NumPy array, let's call it `a`. For such sliding windowed operations, we have a very efficient tool in NumPy as [`strides`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.strides.html), as they are [`views`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.view.html) into the input array without actually making copies.

Let's directly use the methods with the sample data and start with case #1 -

```
In [29]: a  # Input data
Out[29]: array([ 1,  2, 13, 14, 25, 26, 37, 38])

In [30]: m = a.strides[0] # Get strides

In [31]: n = 3 # parameter

In [32]: nrows = a.size - n # Get number of rows in o/p

In [33]: a2D = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a,shape=(nrows,n+1),strides=(m,m))

In [34]: a2D
Out[34]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 13, 14],
       [ 2, 13, 14, 25],
       [13, 14, 25, 26],
       [14, 25, 26, 37],
       [25, 26, 37, 38]])

In [35]: np.may_share_memory(a,a2D) 
Out[35]: True    # a2D is a view into a
```

Case #2 would be similar with an additional parameter for the `Target` column -

```
In [36]: n2 = 3 # Additional param

In [37]: nrows = a.size - n - n2 + 1

In [38]: part1 = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a,shape=(nrows,n),strides=(m,m))

In [39]: part1 # These are D1, D2, D3, etc.
Out[39]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 13],
       [ 2, 13, 14],
       [13, 14, 25]])

In [43]: part2 = a[n+n2-1:] # This is target col

In [44]: part2
Out[44]: array([26, 37, 38])
```

Comment: Thank you @Divakar it works. It is just a little hard for me to understand, but it depends on my lack of knowledge. I will study your solution.

I wonder if there is a solution with pandas instructions.

Comment: @Gilberto Here's a broadcasting based solution to a related problem, if that's easier to follow - http://stackoverflow.com/a/40169790/3293881

Comment: I saw the time results: it's astonishing! It worth hours of study, definitely! Thank you @Divakar again.

Answer (score 0):

I found another method: [view_as_windows](http://scikit-image.org/docs/0.10.x/api/skimage.util.html#view-as-windows)

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows
window_shape = (4, )

aa = np.arange(1000000000) # 1 billion!
bb = view_as_windows(aa, window_shape)
bb

array([[        0,         1,         2,         3],
       [        1,         2,         3,         4],
       [        2,         3,         4,         5],
       ..., 
       [999999994, 999999995, 999999996, 999999997],
       [999999995, 999999996, 999999997, 999999998],
       [999999996, 999999997, 999999998, 999999999]])
```

Around 1 second.

What do you think?